# xUnit in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xunit, dnx

I've got a very simple xUnit test in Visual Studio 2015 ...

```
public class Class1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Blah()
    {
        Assert.Equal(4, 1 + 3);
    }
}
```

But no matter how much I build and clean - I can't get it to appear in the Test Explorer - I've added the xunit.runner.visualstudio nuget package.  But still no joy :(

[image: Tests won't appear in Test Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

You should add `xunit.runner.dnx` runner package instead of `xunit.runner.visualstudio` and be absolutely sure that it matches version table and instructions given here: http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html.

It is also very important to have `test` command in `project.json` file like:

```
"commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
},
```

apparently it is not only for command line

and... I was not able to run it under bleeding edge version like 1.0.0-rc1-15844 so you may want to try it on beta7

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions folder.
2. Install xunit.runner.visualstudio nuget package.